Restoring Navigation Bar Color After Bottom Sheet Closure in Flutter
I'm working on a feature where I want to update the navigation bar color when a bottom sheet is opened, and then revert it back to its original color when the sheet is closed. The code I'm using successfully updates the navigation bar color upon opening the bottom sheet, but it fails to restore it to its previous color once the sheet is closed. Below is the code snippet I've implemented for this functionality:
_openAuthenticationSheet({String title = "", String subTitle = ""}) async {
    // Store the existing overlay style to revert back later
    SystemUiOverlayStyle? existingOverlayStyle = SystemChrome.latestStyle;
    
    // Define the new overlay style with the desired navigation bar color
    var newOverlayStyle = existingOverlayStyle?.copyWith(
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
    );
    
    // Apply the new overlay style
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(newOverlayStyle!);
    
    // Open the bottom sheet
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
        ),
      ),
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              // Redacted lines
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    ).whenComplete(() {
      // Revert back to the original overlay style when the bottom sheet is closed
      SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(existingOverlayStyle!);
    });
  }

I'm facing an issue where the navigation bar color doesn't return to its original state after the bottom sheet is closed. I'm uncertain about what might be causing this problem. I will appreciate any insights or suggestions for resolving this issue.
